# Geometric way to prove $f(z)$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ be analytic in domain D. If $|f(z)|$ is constant, then prove that $f$ is constant. I prove the thing using C-R equations but what I want is geometric approach towards it. Means even without using any method just thinking geometrically is it possible to conclude the given claim.  I like to think of given problem geometrically and get a feel that yes given thing seems obvious like for Rolle's theorem and LMVT. Any other approach?

Comment: The image of $f$ would lie on a circle, but you immediately can show that around any point where $f$ has a nonconstant Taylor series, its image contains a small disc so contradiction

Comment: I believe that use of analycity via the Open Mapping Thm. as in @Conrad's remark will be necessary  (and that the Comment presents that idea in very geometric terms).

Comment: @Conrad I will study your comment after doing Taylor series.

Comment: Sure - geometrically the main property of complex analytic function is that they look like powers of the variable locally, generally like $(z-z_0)$, occasionally like that to a higher power, so you can deduce lots of nice local results easily, the image openess, so containing a two dimensional disc unless constant, being one of them, angle preservation st non-critical points being another, and then multiplying the angle by a positive integer at critical points etc

Comment: @Conrad Ok.. thanks.